# Building a custom iOS framework that uses external frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

I am building a custom framework in iOS which uses AFNetworking, imported through CocoaPods.

If I just build my target for a single architecture all goes well. However, I am using an shell script to build my framework for all architectures, as described [here](http://www.insert.io/frameworkios8xcode6/). When this script tries to build for arm64 it fails with the message `ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking`.

I have tried setting the **Build Active Architecture Only** to NO in the AFNetworking target in the Pods project.

Does anyone know what I am missing here? Is my setup generally ill-advised? Should I avoid using CocoaPods in my framework project? Should I completely avoid using external frameworks like AFNetworking (although I would really like to avoid implementing my own image caching)?

Even if I do get it to build, is this a potential source of conflict if the user is using AFNetworking (perhaps even a different version) in their project?

Answer (score 0):

In your AFNetworking target, make sure your `ARCHS` build setting contains all the architectures you are planning to build for:

[image]